# How do I replace the default messaging icon in the dock with handcent?

Tags: sms, samsung-touchwiz, handcent-sms

I've a Samsung Galaxy S with 2.2 firmware. I'm using handcent instead of the default messaging application. In the default messaging app settings I have disabled notifications and disabled auto-retrieve. But when I get an SMS now, even after I had read it in handcent, I still get the new message notification overlay on the messaging icon on the homescreen until I click into it. Can i disable this, or better yet replace that icon with handcent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default Samsung TouchWiz launcher:

1. Open the App Drawer (Applications)
2. Press Menu, select View Type -> Customizable Grid
3. Press Menu, choose Edit
4. Drag off the Messaging icon, and drag on Handcent.

I've replaced it with Gmail, myself.

Comment: exactly what I needed, I didn't know those dock icons were customizable in this way.

Answer (score 0):

What home screen application are you using? In [Launcher Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fede.launcher), I can long-press on the dock icon, and change the icon and/or shortcut. I can also disable the overlay from `Menu > Preferences > Dock Settings > Missed call count/Unread SMS count/Unread Gmail count`